# Как перегрузить преобразование типов в обобщённом абстрактном классе?

Tags: c#, ооп, generics, перегрузка-функций

Нужно добавить перегрузку преобразований в обобщённый абстрактный класс чтобы все наследники реализовали эту перегрузку.
Что примерно я пытаюсь сделать:

```
    abstract class AStat<T> where T:AStat<T>
    {   
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator T (int x) // метод перегрузки преобразования типов
        {
            return new T{ T.Value = x };
        }
    }

    class S1 :AStat<S1> // класс наследник
    {
        
    }
```

Как видно получается масло масленое при объявлении класса `AStat`.

Данный код не работает по причине "Тип `T`в методе перегрузке преобразования типов не считается типом `AStat`".
Пытался явно преобразовать `T` в `AStat`

`return new (AStat<T>)T{ Value = x };`
Опять масло масленое и тоже не помогает

Пытался сделать так:

```
        {
            return new (T)AStat<T>{ Value = x };
        }
```

Безрезультатно

Я понимаю что данную проблему можно решить просто написав в каждом наследнике метод перегрузки преобразования типов или просто написать не париться вовсе на счёт перегрузки преобразования типов, но хотелось бы узнать как такую проблему можно решить *"красивым"* путём

Comment: Поле `Value` - всегда будет int, или вы хотите в наследниках определять тип этого поля?

Comment: Чтобы принять наиболее полезный ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первая ошибка, которую выдает студия - возможное отсутствие конструктора у типа `T`.

Для решения, необходимо добавить соответствующее ограничение [`new ()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

```
class AStat<T> where T : AStat<T>, new()
```

Следующая ошибка указывает на то, что при пользовательских переопределениях преобразований типов, нужно использовать ближайший тип. В данном случае это не `T`, а `AStat<T>`

```
public static implicit operator AStat<T>(int x)
```

И наконец последняя ошибка: некорректное использование конструктора с блоком инициализации.

Внутри блока нужно обращаться непосредственно к полю

```
return new T { Value = x };
```

После исправления ошибок, код вполне рабочий:

```
abstract class AStat<T> where T : AStat<T>, new()
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator AStat<T>(int x) // метод перегрузки преобразования типов
    {
        return new T { Value = x };
    }
}

class S1 : AStat<S1> // класс наследник
{

}

S1 t = (S1)10; // вернет нужный тип с заполненным свойством `Value`
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Разложили всё по полочкам

Answer (score 2):

Вы почти все правильно сделали, нужно было лишь добавить условие для типа `T` - у него должен быть конструктор без параметров. Также, в перегрузке оператора в качестве возвращаемого типа должен выступать `AStat<T>` Получаем следующее:

```
abstract class AStat<T> where T : AStat<T>, new()
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator AStat<T>(int x)
    {
        return new T {Value = x};
    }
}

class S1 : AStat<S1>
{
}
```

Использование:

```
var s1 = (S1) 4; // s1.Value теперь равно 4
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. При изучении не обобщений не придал значения ограничению ```new()```. Теперь буду знать зачем он нужен